# has_many competitions through teams and inverse_teams

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Thanks for looking. Total noob here. Sorry!

I have a self-referential association to set up a team with two users and a competition through teams:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teams, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :inverse_teams, :class_name => "Team", :foreign_key => "team_mate_id"
  has_many :competitions, :through => :teams
end
```

I'd like to use something like user.competitions but this will only return competitions for teams that directly belong to the user via team.user_id.

What I need is a users competitions for team and inverse team, without showing duplicate results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might simplify things for you to change the model a bit. You maycreate a user model, a team model and a membership model to connect them.
Each Membership belongs to one team and one user. Users have many memberships and Teams have many Memberships as well. I think you can limit that to 2 using validations. Then you can use "has_many through" in order to directly connect Teams to Users and Users to Teams.
This approach will let you get all the competitions for a user with something like:

```
Competition.joins(teams: {memberships: :users}).where(users: {id: my_user_id})
```